# Как работает сериализация?

Tags: javascript, json

1. Метод `toJson` не указываем получим сериализацию (преобразование строке в `JSON`) свойство - значение, функции будут проигнорированы:

```js
var room = {
  number: 23,
  occupy: function() {
    alert( this.number );
  }
};

var event = {
  title: "Конференция",
  date: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1)),
  room: room
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
```

2. Если указать `toJSON` будут сериализованы функции, свойства проигнорированы:

```js
var room = {
  number: 23,
  toJSON: function() {
    console.log( this.number );
  }
};

var event = {
  title: "Конференция",
  date: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1)),
  room: room
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
```

3. Как сериализовать свойства и функции? Я что-то не понял?

Comment: Цитата: `Если преобразуемый в строку объект имеет свойство с именем toJSON и значением свойства, установленным в функцию, то этот метод toJSON() изменит стандартное поведение преобразования в JSON: вместо преобразования объекта будет использоваться значение, возвращаемое методом toJSON().`  То есть в toJSON вы сами пишите то, что надо сделать, а не "будут сериализованы функции, свойства проигнорированы"

Comment: @Сергей Мишин  я правильно понял toJSON указываем как сериализовать объект ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JSON - нет типа функций, поэтому функции **не сериализуются** никак.

---

Если у сериализуемого объекта присутствует метод [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior), то вместо дальнейшей сериализации этого объекта будет использовано значение, которое вернет данная функция.